# How to create game controller property sheet?

Tags: controller, directx, wdk

I want create custom property sheet for joystick that i developed. Some relevant stuff about find in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538689(v=vs.85).aspx. But this docs about WinME and NT 4.0 and about deprecated stuff such as dicpl.h. Also it docs link to DirectX Driver Development Kit (DDK). Google don't give any useful information about it. I think i also old and deprecated stuff.

Any ideas or advises comrades?